# RegEx string start/end/middle one time match

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to validate `input` field with regex.
Task is: `input` field can (optional) contain only one special character `*` at start or middle or at the end of string.
Here is my regex:

```
^(?!.?\*.*\()[\w*]+$
```

Problem is: string still valid to multiple `*` and can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?!(?:[^*]*\*){2})[\w*]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XyvAYC/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!(?:[^*]*\*){2})` - no two not necessarily consecutive asterisks allowed in the string
- `[\w*]+` - one or more letters, digits, `_` or `*` chars
- `$` - end of string

Comment: Looks like what i'm looking for. Thank you!